# Copying Xcode .app file will cause any security issue?

Tags: xcode, security

If I copy my Xcode's .app file to another system, will It contain any personal data in it? PassKeys for example..

And if yes, What should I do after copying it to prevent from security problems?

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode .app doesn't contain personal security information. These things are stored elsewhere, for example some things are in your OS-level "keychain".

To clarify something, a .app is actually a folder containing a bunch of files. You can right-click it and select "show contents" to see what's inside.

I also expect that copying the .app file will not accomplish what you hope. There are other things installed when you install Xcode that won't be there (e.g. iOS SDKs which are at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`).

Comment: thank you, can you add a resource link for your answer please?

+I've copied and Xcode worked as well as copying it from a dmg file, as I expected.

Comment: SDKs aren't included in the .app though. Just look through the "contents" inside the app, and you won't see SDKs there. So if you need to compile an iOS app against say the iOS 9 SDK, it won't work if you just copy Xcode over. Unless of course that SDK was installed earlier for some other reason.

Comment: When you use .dmg file, you actually copy the .app file, and of course the SDK files are included, too. (And I've checked the content, they are!) My only problem was to know about personal data; don't you know any official reference for it? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not saying copying it from a .dmg. It is no longer clear to me what your question is.

Comment: No, I mean copying it from a .app file or a .dmg file doesn't have any difference in SDK or related content.

Comment: `.app` is not a file, it's a folder. If the `.dmg` contains *an installer* then it's completely different from copying a `.app`.

Comment: but Xcode installer only copies Xcode to Applications folder, Am I wrong? So, why copy did worked in my case?

Comment: I can't answer that without much more information. If you're just building a plain C project, there's no need for SDKs.

Comment: No I'm talking about iOS application programming, and it worked really :/

Comment: It's likely you ran an installer, and it installed Xcode and the iOS SDK. Just copying the .app won't do that.